# How to test React dynamic style prop?

Tags: css, reactjs, testing, jestjs

Am teaching myself React and am starting on testing. Using the recommended stuff from the docs... create-react-app, jest, testing-library/react. I have a component that renders a dynamic style, something like this

```
const ScalingDiv = (props) => (
    <StyledDiv size={props.size || 42}>
        <OtherEl>
            {props.text}
        </OtherEl>
    </StyledDiv>
);
```

I would like to verify that my logic in there is working correctly (that 42 is used as a fallback size). I cannot find any examples or docs of this. I had hoped that something like this would work-

```
test('check fallback size', async () => {
    const {container} = render(<ScalingDiv/>);
    expect(container.firstChild).toHaveAttribute('size', 42);
});
```

But I haven't found any combination of matchers and queries that returns ANY attributes. Then I tried to just check the style directly using jest-dom, but `toHaveStyle('this_isnt_valid_css: 199')` passes- I couldn't stick anything in there to get it to fail. So... what is the right way to do this?

Comment: "But I haven't found any combination of matchers and queries that returns ANY attributes" -- 
jest-dom has [toHaveAttribute](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tohaveattribute) and you try: expect(button).toHaveAttribute('type', expect.stringContaining('sub'))

Answer (score 1):

It's not attribute but `prop`. So we can refer to [`prop()`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/prop.html) and [`props()`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/props.html) methods like

```
expect(container.firstChild.prop('size')).toEqual(42);
```

or

```
expect(container.firstChild.props()).toEqual({
  size: 42
});
```